# Change default python coding style

Tags: python, pylint

In python i'm following **camelCase** Naming style. I checked my code with "pylint" and it gives error for not following **lower_case_with_underscores** style. Also i use netBeans IDE for coding. This IDE gives warning for not following **lower_case_with_underscores** style.

How to tell pylint and netBeans that i'm following camelCase naming style, not lower_case_with_underscores??

Thanks.

Comment: Note that while that's perfectly valid under some circumstances, it's usually best to use the most common coding style in the language/framework/... if you don't have a compelling reason to do otherwise, even if it's not your personal preference.

Comment: Just don't use netBeans IDE and don't use camel case.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use `pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc` to get a standard `pylintrc`.

Edit the file, go to the [BASIC] section, and change the following regexps:

- `function-rgx=_?_?[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}$`
- `method-rgx=_?_?[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}$`
- `attr-rgx=_?_?[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}$`
- `argument-rgx=_?[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}$`
- `variable-rgx=_?[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}$`
- `inlinevar-rgx=_?[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}$`

You may also want to change `module-rgx` while you are at it, and look around for other settings that you may want to customize to suite your style.

Comment: Can you share any documentation on how to do all this.

Answer (score 13):

**Accepted answer is outdated. Now its much simpler:**

Use `pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc` to get a standard pylintrc.

Edit the file, go to the [BASIC] section, and change the different `...-naming-styles` to `camelCase`.

Answer (score 2):

for netbeans 8.0.2 ...

Tools --> Options --> Editor --> Hints --> Python --> Naming Conventions --> Functions --> mixedCase

Answer (score 0):

In VS-Code use this `settings.json` entry to have variable naming style and function naming style set to "camelCase",

```json
    "pylint.args": [
      "--variable-naming-style=camelCase",
      "--function-naming-style=camelCase"
    ]
```

choose arguments as per your requirements,
[Pylint Documentation](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/convention/invalid-name.html#predefined-naming-styles):